# Why isn't my function for getting the smallest value from a list working

Tags: python, list, function, loops, iteration

I made a function for getting the smallest value from a list but it is not working properly and returning the wrong value. It prints out 5. What is wrong with it?

```
def finding_least_num(a_list):
    first = 0
    for i in a_list:
        while first < len(a_list)-1:
            if i < a_list[first]:
                min_num = a_list[first]
            first = first + 1
        first = 0
    print(min_num)
finding_least_num([3,7,5,2,9])
```

Comment: I don't understand the multiple loops. Also, after the `if` statement, shouldn't the minimum number be `i`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why there are a lot of inner if and while statements. @Swishy has diagnosed the problem you are sticking with correctly. if you are insisting on not using `min` function, you can try code below:

```py
def finding_least_num(a_list):
    first = float('inf')
    for value in a_list:
      if value < first:
        first = value
    return first
```

which results in `2` in the case of using `[3,7,5,2,9]` as an input for the function.

Note that `float("inf")` is referring to the maximum number available in python.

Answer (score 2):

```
if i < a_list[first]:
```

This is your problem, this instead needs to be:

```
if min_num > a_list[first]
```

It doesn't work because you are not checking against the lowest number you have saved already in min_num. You also need to initialize `min_num` to the first record in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
def finding_least_num(a_list):
    first = 0
    for i in a_list:
        print("testing i = ", i)
        while first < len(a_list)-1:
            print("first = ", first)
            if i < a_list[first]:
                print ("checking if i < ", a_list[first])
                print("i", i)
                min_num = a_list[first]
                print("minimum number here is ", min_num)
           first = first + 1
        first = 0
    print(min_num)
finding_least_num([3,7,5,2,9])
```

I rewrote your code with comments and run it. Copy this into your interpreter and you will see the error and the reason why you received 5 each time. You will realize that your first for loop takes the first index of the array you passed to the function and tests it against the second while loop (let's call it chosen index). For each cycle the selected index is tested if it is less than the chosen index. If true set the minimum number as the chosen index. If you test the new code I have up there with the prints you will discover the last minimum number recorded is what was returned after the two loops completed. Python has many methods to help in these instances. For  example [min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) is a very good way to simplify things. Another good way is to [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) the array and return the first or last index depending on the order of the sorting.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I am aware there are methods to help but since I am a beginner, I wanted to work it out completely on my own. Your solution helped a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: I am happy to help.